# Which programs configure the network based on the settings in /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: debian, network-interface, networkmanager, utilities, administration

I have installed Stretch and I find that NetworkManager gets in my way more often than not, and I would rather familiarize myself with network interface administration at a lower level based on the contents of /etc/network/interfaces.

Which command line programs take over the task network configuration when NetworkManager is disabled?

There are a number of programs like `ip`, `ifconfig`, `iwconfig`, and `wicd` it is hard to tell which of these are used by `/etc/network/interfaces` to configure network settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this, follow the trail starting with `/etc/network/interfaces`, or rather the corresponding manpage, [`interfaces.5`](https://manpages.debian.org/interfaces.5). A search reveals that it comes from [`ifupdown`](https://packages.debian.org/ifupdown) or [`ifupdown2`](https://packages.debian.org/ifupdown2). Looking at the corresponding package dependencies shows that they use `iproute2`, and can optionally use `ppp`, `rdnssd`, and a DHCP client.

Reading the manpage provides additional detail, in particular concerning wireless support which is provided by [`wireless-tools`](https://packages.debian.org/wireless-tools) and [`iw`](https://packages.debian.org/iw). [Many other packages](https://manpages.debian.org/ifupdown/interfaces.5#OPTIONS_PROVIDED_BY_OTHER_PACKAGES) provide `ifupdown` extensions.